# max and min of $f(x,y)$ on the curve $xy^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $f(x,y)={{x^3}\over{y^2}} e^{{-x}\over{y}}$. If I consider the function bounded at the curve I found $g(y)={1\over y^8}e^{-{1 \over y^3}}$.
g is defined in $(0,+\infty)$ ,

$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^+}g(y)=0^+ $,

$\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}g(y)=0^+ $,

g has a global max in $y=({3 \over 8})^{1 \over 3}$

and so $f(x,y)$ has a global max in $(({8 \over 3})^{2 \over 3},({3 \over 8})^{1 \over 3})$ and Inf f=$0$?

Comment: Looks right to me!